# MySQL UUID alternative - more randomness

Tags: mysql

I have a table with thousands of rows, this table has a column of `guid`. This is normally generated in the code, and that works fine.

However, this time, a batch import was performed and does not contain UUID values. I need to now update this table so that it does properly have UUID values.

The problem I'm running into is that when I execute the following in a loop:

```
(select uuid())
```

It's not *random* enough. Meaning that internally, the machine (name?) and timestamp are used to generate the uuid, which in tern results in hundreds of thousands of rows receiving super similar UUID's.

I can't generate this at the software stack, unfortunately, so I'm wondering if anyone has any tips or good solutions for this.

**Edit** For those close votes:

When using `(select uuid())` in an `update` command on thousands of rows, it relies on the machine (node) and the timestamp. Because thousands upon thousands of rows are updated within microseconds of each other, this produces an unfortunately similar string across all rows, for example:

```
1a5e308e-5530-11e7-a853-932d273ec009
1a5e3160-5530-11e7-a853-932d273ec009
1a5e32a0-5530-11e7-a853-932d273ec009
```

Would be the first 3 uuid's generated and applied to the first 3 rows in the update query. This is problematic because these UUID's are used in a greater part of a concatenated string that is visible to the frontend. Because of this, the end result is that these become guessable, and therefore represent a possible angle for a vector attack.

My purpose in asking this question is if there is another way to generate a 16 character, 128 byte string that follows the same pattern as a `UUID` does, but perhaps has more uniqueness from one iteration to the next.

I hope I was clear enough in this explanation.

Comment: Similar, or identical?  If they're only similar (but still unique), then what's the issue?

Comment: Not sure what is the issue.  What does it mean by "super similar" and why does it has to be "super dissimilar" to work?  Does your code rely on a degree of similarities in two or more UUIDs?

Comment: A UUID is [*defined*](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc4122) to contain a node identifier and a timestamp. If you don't have those, it isn't a UUID.

Comment: @OliverCharlesworth The problem is that the GUID is actually visible on the front end. It's part of another string and because of the similar likeness to other UUID's that are generated, it is guessable and therefore a security concern.

Comment: @AllenKing For instance, if ran in an `update` command, it will generate very similar UUID's: `3893eac4-555f-11e7-a853-932d273ec009`, `3934eac4-555f-11e7-a853-932d273ec009`, would be the next one in the iteration. This is a concern from a security stand point.

Comment: @EJP Absolutely, and I'm not disputing this either. However, through the software stack, we're not using true UUID's but rather a string that matches the same 16 character, 128-byte sequence, just generated in such a way that they don't rely on a timestamp for uniqueness, therefore giving the allusion that there isn't such a specific pattern to the generation of said string

Comment: @EJP Sorry - I misspoke above. The software stack's generation of the UUID does rely on the timestamp, but generates a more unique string from iteration to iteration due to how the string is built.

Comment: So *what's the question?* You can't do it from the software stack? but you can? So you do need to use MySQL `UUID`? But you don't?

Comment: A uuid is _never_ cryptographically secure and is guessable even if they are further apart. If you need to make them unguessable you can't use UUID's.

Comment: @Evert I understand that, however, I don't have any choice, I'm working with legacy code and this is my life. It's *nice* to do what I can to avoid this, I'm still asking the question above to see if i can find a more "random" 16 character 128-byte string.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This function generates completely random UUIDs in MySQL (tested with MySQL 5.6)

```
select LOWER(CONCAT(
    LPAD(HEX(ROUND(rand()*POW(2,32))), 8, '0'), '-',
    LPAD(HEX(ROUND(rand()*POW(2,16))), 4, '0'), '-',
    LPAD(HEX(ROUND(rand()*POW(2,16))), 4, '0'), '-',
    LPAD(HEX(ROUND(rand()*POW(2,16))), 4, '0'), '-',
    LPAD(HEX(ROUND(rand()*POW(2,48))), 12, '0')
))
```

Note that it's not a UUIDv4 because it doesn't have bits that indicate version 4 or variant (See [UUIDv4 on Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universally_unique_identifier#Version_4_(random))) - instead it's completely random (or, more precisely, as random as MySQL's [RAND()](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/mathematical-functions.html#function_rand) function can generate)

Answer (score 2):

You mentioned that it was a security concern when similar `UUID` were used in neighboring records.  Here is how you can make it better very easily:

```
SELECT MD5(UUID());
```

or

```
SELECT sha1(UUID());
```

Nobody can guess the next ID in this case.  If you need only 16 chars, perhaps you can do `SELECT LEFT(MD5(UUID()),16)`.  There could be a chance of collision but the chance will still be very remote because MD5 will provide 
 340,000,000,000,000,000,000,000,000,000,000,000,000 possible unique outputs and even first 16 characters will have a great many combinations.

Comment: This will not give you the typical `uuid` format of hyphens between each section of the `uuid`. I.E. `xxxx-xxx-xxxxxx`

Comment: Why are those dashes needed anyway?  If there is a logic that checks the dashes, something is not right with the logic.  UUID is simply a unique string, and the logic should treat it that way.